# How to turn off blinking LED while suspend?

Tags: suspend

When Ubuntu is in suspend mode, power led is blinking.

Is there a way to turn it off?

Comment: you could probably find an answer having a look around /sys/class/leds/[yourLED]/power/control (replace [yourLED] accourdingly)

Comment: Already looked there on two computers. On desktop there was nothing, on laptop there were two other leds.

Comment: What's the output of `ls /sys/class/leds/` on the machine you're trying to do this? (or is this for multiple machines?)

Comment: This is for multiple machines. I do no see anywhere any relevant LED in that directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is hardware specific. If you cannot change the setting in the BIOS of your PC, the next way would be to remove the LED connector from your mainboard, which would effectively turn off the LED completely.

You could also try to hibernate instead of suspend, if that's an option.

Comment: For a laptop it is not an option. Hibernate turns it off, but I look for a way to turn it off in suspend, if possible.

Comment: It looks like this LED is controlled by bios. There is no way to turn it off from OS, unless there is a hardware specific way or option in bios.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I know you are looking for general option.

**Some Dell laptops** have:

> **Unobtrusive Mode**
>
> When enabled, pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> turns off all light and sound
>   emissions in the system. Press <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to resume normal operation.
>
> Enable Unobtrusive Mode: By default it is disabled.

Reference: [Dell Latitude 3340 Owner's Manual](http://www.dell.com/support/manuals/ar/en/ardhs1/Topic/latitude-3340-laptop/DellLatitude_3340_OM-v2/en-us/GUID-BE8D0A84-6B57-46F3-B807-5D976401350A)

1. Open power menu and move mouse pointer to sleep button.
2. Press <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to turn off all lights and sounds.
3. Click sleep button.

I have Latitude E6430 and it works well, power led is off. There are other model I see their manuals on the net like: Latitude E5440, Precision M6800, Latitude E6530 ..